# Reading variables from text files

Tags: python

I have a text file, `xyz.txt` that has variables, and I want to use those variables, I know how to read them but do not know how to use it and call them when I need it. For example, If in the text file there is `x = 123` I would like to be able to call on that variable for use, so if i said `print x` it would give me `123`.

text file:

```
x = 1.000
y = 2.343
z = 3.000
```

Later on It will have more data.

Comment: Could you provide more information on what exactly this text file looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to do it is to load the content of your file and then use `execfile(file_content)`, then you will be able to make `print x` and it will print the content of `x`.

Comment: `eval()` can only evaluate expressions, and assignments are statements.  This won't work.  You could use `execfile("xyz.txt")`, but a much better idea is to use the `ConfigParser` module, expecially if the text file is from an untrusted source.

Answer (score 4):

One solution might be using a **dictionary**:

```
vars = dict()

with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        eq_index = line.find('=')
        var_name = line[:eq_index].strip()
        number = float(line[eq_index + 1:].strip())
        vars[var_name] = number

print(vars)
```

And the `file.txt`:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
d = 4
variable = 5
```

So, if you want to see the `variable` value you just do:

```
print(vars["variable"])
```